# how to save image using asp.net and save it in access 2007 database

Tags: asp.net

Iam working in (web registration students program ) using Microsoft viual basic 2010 (asp.net)
so i want to know which tool is compatible & how to save the image for each student ,save the path using  Microsoft access 2007 database ,,,,,,

I hope to solve my problem,
Anyway ,thank u.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, If you want to save the image as such into database this would help - [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/263945/how-to-save-image-in-ms-access-database). Otherwise if you want upload the image to webserver and store the path to database, you could use an [html file upload control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569565/uploading-files-in-asp-net-without-using-the-fileupload-server-control)