# How can I show up OpenFileDialog class in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, openfiledialog

I want to show up an OpenFileDialog box in my ASP .NET web application. I am writing in c#. I  want to create a user account with an image so I need to select image from my computer and save it into a database. How can I implement it.

Comment: You're looking for a FileUpload element.. not an OpenFileDialog (which is WinForms).

Comment: add a `<asp:fileupload>` control and read the documentation.

Comment: @RQDQ: it's explicitely stated in the question that the app is ASP.NEt

Comment: I've retagged the question to avoid future confusion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You **can** do that using

```
   <input type="file"  id="fileLoader" name="files" title="Load File" ...
```

The usual trick is to make it *invisible*, and on clicking some *visible* artifact (`styled link`, `image`, `button`... whatever) *simulate* a click on `fileLoader`:

```
 $("#fileLoader").click();
```

Answer (score 3):

you cannot use that Windows Forms class in ASP.NET, you should use the [FileUpload class/control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx).

Or see other alternatives: [Uploading Files in ASP.net without using the FileUpload server control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569565/uploading-files-in-asp-net-without-using-the-fileupload-server-control)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. `OpenFileDialog` is something for desktop applications.

Comment: it's clear that OP is asking about *analogy*. He's just "navigating in space", searching for some solution.

Comment: @Tigran: you may be right, but I think you and I have different definitions of the word "clear".

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same as Tigran's above but I found I needed to change the JavaScript slightly to use getElementById("...") to identify the button to click(). If I just did this in HTML/CSS Tigran's code worked fine but when I used it within an .aspx file I required the change.

.aspx

```
<input type="file" id="fileLoader" name="files" title="Load File" />   
<asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server"  Text="ASP click Me" onclientclick="openfileDialog()"  />
```

JavaScript

```
function openfileDialog() {
         document.getElementById("fileLoader").click();
     }
```

css

```
#fileLoader{
display:none;}
```