# InnerHTML attribute Shows The Tags at String

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, content-management-system, innerhtml

Hello Im Developing a Simple Cms That Generate Blogs
however, The User Should enter The Blog Content buy im self and let him to do that with tinymce editor Now i save The Content OF that in a data base he Type of that database element is "Text" so far so good Right ? 
the problem is when i get the Content from the data base and a sign it with inner HTml it became like in that picture[`Here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6LYd.png) 
Here is the Html Code

```html
 `boddy.InnerHtml = " <div id='shareButtonsDiv'><div class='iframe_header'>
                                 <p>" & DetailsView1.Rows(0).Cells(1).Text & "</p>
                                 <span class='social_icons'>
                                     <span>Share on</span>
                                   <span class='twitter'>
                                       <a target='_blank' class='twitter-share-button'
                                           href='https://twitter.com/share'
                                          data-size='large'
                                          data-text='custom share text'
                                           data-url='https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button'
                                          data-hashtags='example,demo'
                                          data-via='twitterdev'
                                          data-related='twitterapi,twitter'>
                                           <i class='fa fa-twitter' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>
                                    </span>
                                      <span class='facebook'>
                                          <script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=1074461072666302';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
                                          <div class='fb-share-button' data-href='../blogs/1_1.html' data-layout='button' data-mobile-iframe='true'>                                            <a class='fb-xfbml-parse-ignore' target='_blank' href='https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse'>Share</a>
                                          </div>
                                     </span>
                                 </span>
                             </div>  

                                   </div>
                                 
        <div class='iframe_content'>
 <div class='texts'>
   
    " + DetailsView1.Rows(2).Cells(1).Text + "
   
  </div>
 
 </div> "`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that your HTML code is escaped/encoded. Try using the [**`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim Header As String = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(DetailsView1.Rows(0).Cells(1).Text)
Dim Texts As String = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(DetailsView1.Rows(2).Cells(1).Text)
```

...then concatenate the HTML with those two variables instead.

Comment: Glad I could help! Good luck!

Comment: Man i have been trying for 3 hours now 
why i cant declare OpenFileDialog with VB ?
i imported  System.Windows.Forms 
still why is that ?

Comment: ASP.NET is serverside only. The only way to display an OFD is to put an `<input type="file">` tag or a  `<asp:FileUpload>` tag in your HTML code. This can be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12914552/3740093

Comment: I Declared A OpenfileDialog i want it to pick files only the problem is when i use the showdialog() the page strat loading and nothing shows 
and the page keeps loading why is that ?? thats the problem that im having

Comment: Like I said: _**ASP.NET is serverside ONLY!**_ That is, the C#/VB.NET code is only run at the server, not the client. You _**MUST**_ use some kind of file upload element. Using a regular `OpenFileDialog` is _**not possible**_.