# Using "<input type="file" .... />" instead of asp:FileUpload

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, file-upload

I'm modifying an existing ASP.NET project.  The original author erroneously tried to create a styled asp:FileUpload by setting its visibility to hidden and just creating two custom styled browse and save buttons.

For security reason, IE does not permit this.  My strategy is to instead try to use input tags with type="file", like [this example](http://htmlcampus.com/style-a-file-browse-button-with-css/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20HTMLCampus%20%28HTML%20Campus%29).  So if I set up the input like `<input type="file" ID="inputFile" />`  how do I access/save the file in my code behind, `inputFile.SaveAs("someFile.txt");`?  Also (in code behind) can I do something like `inputFile.HasFile` or is there some other analog of this?

As per recommendations I'm trying something like the following:

```
             <td>
                Enabled: <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <div id="testFileUploader">>
                   <input type="file" id="browserHidden" runat="server" />
                   <div id="browserVisible"><input type="text" id="fileField" /></div>
                </div>
             </td>
```

Comment: Just add a runat="server" to it.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to include this.  Thanks.  What about accessing it in the code behind, do `.SaveAs()` and `.HasFile` work on the `inputFile` object?

Comment: Included in my answer. :)

Comment: @kmarks2 you don't need to set runat="server" for a plain HTML form elements everywhere, setting always runat is required for asp: elements, for the plain HTML, just set once runat at the main form, and then you will be able to get html resource of any plain html object from a Request, loot at my answer.

Comment: @kmarks2 please, don't forget to mark a helpful answer by clicking on accept icon

Answer (score 14):

So, you can generate a random file name for the a future upload, based on the `GUID` at the `CodeBehind` of ASPX page:

```
HttpPostedFile filePosted = Request.Files["uploadFieldNameFromHTML"];

if (filePosted != null && filePosted.ContentLength > 0)
{
    string fileNameApplication = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePosted.FileName);
    string fileExtensionApplication = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileNameApplication);

    // generating a random guid for a new file at server for the uploaded file
    string newFile = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + fileExtensionApplication;
    // getting a valid server path to save
    string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("uploads"), newFile);

    if (fileNameApplication != String.Empty)
    {
        filePosted.SaveAs(filePath);
    }
}
```

For `Request.Files["uploadFieldNameFromHTML"]` set the ID in HTML code here:

```
<input type='file' id='...' />
```

Also, don't forget to define `runat="server"` at the main form in ASPX page, it's better to set it at the main form and don't forget about `enctype="multipart/form-data"` parameter of the `<form>`:

```
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type='file' id='uploadFieldNameFromHTML' />
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a runat="server" to the object. This way it will work on the CodeBehid just like any asp:FileUpload control.

Comment: I've edited my original post to reflect doing it this way.  But now I cannot build because I get errors everything I try to do `browserHidden.HasFile` or `browserHidden.SaveAs("someFile.txt")`, etc .  Indeed it seems that nothing that pops in in Intellisence on when I type `browser.` seems to let me save the file.  How can I do this on an input object?

Answer (score 1):

As commented you can add the runat="server" to you input file tag.

By another hand, there is already a similar post about what you're asking for. Check this out:

[Uploading Files in ASP.net without using the FileUpload server control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569565/uploading-files-in-asp-net-without-using-the-fileupload-server-control)

Hope this help

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(fileUrunResim.HasFile)
    fileUrunResim.SaveAs(MapPath("~/Images/" + fileUrunResim.FileName));


**if you unique filename,**

string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileUrunResim.FileName);

string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 25) + extension ;


if(fileUrunResim.HasFile)
    fileUrunResim.SaveAs(MapPath("~/Images/" + filename ));
```