# Trouble with uploaded files in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I know how I can upload a file (i.e. PDF file) in ASP.NET. How can I do some operation on this file after it had been uploaded?

For example, I need to correct the wrong words, or another application is for some plagiarism system.

Comment: Does this post give you a startup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569565/uploading-files-in-asp-net-without-using-the-fileupload-server-control

Comment: You can try this one - https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F83152%2Freading-pdf-documents-in-net&ei=I2zpVJD5C4eiugTdh4KgBg&usg=AFQjCNGFsRvIHshACGmzf2OX1swMhRZlqw&sig2=7T_xbtwShJscgfglcuBi3g&bvm=bv.86475890,d.c2E