# Uploading Image to Server from NameValueCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, http-post, namevaluecollection

I am using ASP.net 4.5 with VB.net

**This is my TestPage.aspx code**

```
    <%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Master.master"  AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="TestPage.aspx.vb" Inherits="TestPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderMaster" runat="Server">

                        <form role="form" method="post" id="Test_form" action="TestPageLOAD.aspx"

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="headline" name="headline" />

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="fileUpload btn btn-default">
                                    <span>Upload article image</span>
                                    <input type='file' id="imgInp" name="imgInp" class="upload" />
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <button  type="submit" name="submitReport" id="submitReport">SUBMIT REPORT</button>
                        </form>

</asp:Content>
```

**This is my TestPageLOAD.aspx.vb code on Page_Load Event**

```
 Dim nvc As NameValueCollection = Request.Form()

    lblHeadline.text = nvc("headline")

    Dim MyFileToUpload As String
    MyFileToUpload = nvc("imgInp")

    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FolderPathDOC As String

    FolderPath = "~/pics/"

    If MyFileToUpload.HasFile Then

        Dim strFileName As String
        Dim Extention As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(MyFileToUpload.PostedFile.FileName)
        Dim NoExtention As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(MyFileToUpload.PostedFile.FileName)

        strFileName = NoExtention + "_logo" + Extention.Substring(Extention.LastIndexOf("."))

        Dim filePath As [String] = Server.MapPath(FolderPath & strFileName)

        MyFileToUpload.SaveAs(filePath)

    End If
```

Now this code works fine populating or saving the data on the TestPageLOAD.aspx.vb, but I cant upload the image on this LOAD page. Is there a way around it? I do not want to change the controls to ASP.net controls on the TestPage.aspx as it needs to stay plain HTML. But now uploading the image is now my problem.....

VB.net or C# code will be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this code and this did the job at the end.

```
<form action="TestPageLOAD.aspx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="imgInp" />
</form>
```

Page_Load Event on TestPageLOAD.aspx.cs

```
if(Request.Files["imgInp"] != null)
{
    HttpPostedFile MyFile = Request.Files["imgInp"];
    //Setting location to upload files
    string TargetLocation = Server.MapPath("~/pics/");
    try
    {
        if (MyFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                //Determining file name. You can format it as you wish.
                string FileName = MyFile.FileName;
                //Determining file size.
                int FileSize = MyFile.ContentLength;
                //Creating a byte array corresponding to file size.
                byte[] FileByteArray = new byte[FileSize];
                //Posted file is being pushed into byte array.
                MyFile.InputStream.Read(FileByteArray, 0, FileSize);
                //Uploading properly formatted file to server.
                MyFile.SaveAs(TargetLocation + FileName);
            }
        }
     catch(Exception BlueScreen)
     {
         //Handle errors
     }
}
```

All thanks to: [Uploading Files in ASP.net without using the FileUpload server control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569565/uploading-files-in-asp-net-without-using-the-fileupload-server-control)