# C#.net equivalent for JS .on()

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, save

I have an aspx page with `<input type='file'>` elements. I want to use C# to save the files uploaded via these controls. I've seen certain solutions (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569565/uploading-files-in-asp-net-without-using-the-fileupload-server-control)), which I can use in `On_Load`. Problem is my `input` controls will be created dynamically using JS, and I don't want a postback each time an image is uploaded.

Is there some equivalent method in C# to JS's `.on()` method, so that I can attach a handler to future controls?

**EDIT:** As suggested by @Oceans, I added an `onchange` event handler inside the `input` control:

`<input type="file" onchange="saveFile" runat="server">`

And I have a `saveFile` handler in my `.cs` behind:

```
protected void saveFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var imagesDir = Server.MapPath("Images/");
    var uploader = sender as FileUpload;
    uploader.PostedFile.SaveAs(imagesDir + uploader.PostedFile.FileName);
}
```

When I choose a file via the `input` control the function `saveFile` is not ran. I replaced `onchange="saveFile"` with `onchange="alert('hi')"` to check if the event is being fired and it is, so I'm obviously missing something... probably something to do with `postback` and `.asp` page cycle?

Comment: Make sure that the input is part of a form. You can also trigger the post method this way.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you're describing an [`EventHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx). Perhaps [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w2tb12s.aspx) about creating event handlers in an ASP.NET web form page might be of use to you.

If I understand you correctly, you wish to upload files as soon as they get selected. The html upload file control supports the `onChange` event to handle this. When creating the controls dynamically you should just define the onChange with it. For security reasons it's not really recommended to automatically upload files.

You'd get something like this:

```
<input type='file' onChange='MyEventHandler' runat='server'>

<script runat="server">
    protected void MyEventHandler(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
</script>
```

I suggest you read the following [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323246) and as you seem familiar with JavaScript [this](http://www.bitsmonkey.com/2014/04/simply-notes-2-single-click-file-upload.html) might be of use to you aswell.

Comment: I do no need to add `EventHandlers`, but how can I do this for elements that have not yet been created? JS's `.on()` does exactly that... and that's what I'm after.

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly, I hope it helps you forward.