# How to upload multiple files with jansy-bootstrap file upload?

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload

I'm using [jansy bootstrap](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/) to replace the asp.net `FileUpload`. I've successfully retrieved the file using `HttpPostedFile` with the help of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569565/uploading-files-in-asp-net-without-using-the-fileupload-server-control):

```
HttpPostedFile image = Request.Files["myFile"];
```

Now, how do I allow **multiple files** to be selected? With the asp.net `FileUpload` it was simply adding `AllowMultiple="True"` parameter and then in the code behind I simply looped through:

```
foreach (var image in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
{...}
```

How do I do this with a custom control? THis is my current html (which is the first [Image Upload Widget example](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput-examples)):

```
<div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
    <div class="fileinput-preview thumbnail" data-trigger="fileinput" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"></div>
    <div>
        <span class="btn btn-default btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Select image</span><span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>
          <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile"></span>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `multiple` attribute and set its value to `multiple` to allow select of multiple files

```
<input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile" multiple="multiple">
```

Comment: thank you for your help! I did think it may have just been an extra parameter. I now have another minor problem with the display of multiple images, would you mind [taking a look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34435976/jansy-bootstrap-file-upload-doesnt-show-multiple-files)? Thanks again!