# Pass File Path when using <input type="file">

Tags: html, asp.net

I read that for security reason, the uploaded file path is not displayed or cannot be read or changed (althought I can read it in the textbox that is displayed beside the upload button)

Here is my requirement

I have html page which contains unknown number of textbox and upload button because its generated dynamically and webform1.aspx which will handle the reading and database (access) processing.

If I have 15 question, each question has 3 input (the answer, remark, photo), that mean i will have 15 answer, and 15 remark and 15 photo

I managed to handle the answer and remark in my webform.aspx by doing this:

```
For i = 0 to Request.Form.Count -1
    Response.Write(Request.Form(i))
    Response.Write(Chr(13)+Chr(10))
Next
```

I want to insert the phote into database (access attachment) which is not the problem here, but the problem is getting the image file path or, the image binary data (15 image)

I have one submit button, because when the user finish entering the answers and remarks and photos he will submit them all, not one by one.

I tried with multipart/form-data and without but I could not know where to get the images uploaded.

```html
<form action="webform1.aspx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

How do I get the path of the selected photo? **loop the images uploaded** ?

Comment: I find the solution in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569565/uploading-files-in-asp-net-without-using-the-fileupload-server-control

All I needed is Request.Files(i)

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution in here: stackoverflow.com/questions/569565/… All I needed is Request.Files(i)