# How to create file from local machine to online web server?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to create a file from a local computer directly onto a web server?

I tried but got this error:

> URI format not supported.

My code is:

```
 string path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/");
 string path = "http://www.domainname.com/App_Data/";
 string jsondata = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(enquirydet);
 System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + "enq.json", jsondata);
```

Any way how I can do that?

Comment: Creating a file directly on web server is not that simple. Are you able to browse that folder of web server from local machine? Are you able to create file there directly without using your code?

Comment: I can do it using ftp details, which I have.

Comment: then ftp the file

Comment: If the location is not publicly accessible then your code can't create file there just like that.

Comment: In your code there is a syntax error. you can't create two variables with the same name like you have `path`.

Comment: Yes variable one path is commented already. How should I upload file using ftp in asp.net c#

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading Files in ASP.net without using the FileUpload server control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569565/uploading-files-in-asp-net-without-using-the-fileupload-server-control)

Comment: what you trying can cause security problems, creating file/folder on remote server. Here is what i suggested, create a method that, accept your params and create on the file/folder on server side.