# SaveFileDialog control is not displayed in Toolbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am developing by using Asp.net/C#, and on designing .aspx Web Form page; I need to use SaveFileDialog control.

The control in MS Visual Studio-Community 2015 is not displayed in the Toolbox (left side), where I chose it in the .Net Components window.

so what to do ?

Comment: Where are you going to run this Save File Dialog?  On the client?  The "user agent" (i.e., the browser) is what controls the client.  Your C# code is running on the server.

Comment: @Flydog57 I am designing .aspx page so I want to view the SaveFileDialog on the browser for client interaction

Comment: SaveFiledialog is for windows forms, not asp. You should google for how to select file in browser

Comment: When a user causes a file to be downloaded to his/her browser, then the browser should pop up a Save As dialog.  You don't control that.

Comment: @T.S. But I created a Windows Form which is based on ASP.net.

Comment: @Flydog57 Exactly, that I want from the user to choose the file > and save it in somewhere. But I can't find the control where online I found many people used it in ASP.NET.

Comment: You say you are "designing .aspx Web Form page".  That's a web page, not a Windows Form.  You don't have any control over that Save As dialog, the user and the browser does.  What you have control of are the link(s) he/she might click, the mime-types associated with those links, etc.

Comment: you really need to sort yourself. You use `WinForms` or `Asp.net`. I probably know better than you; what are you using - you using `Asp.net WEB forms` So, you need to open GOOGLE and search for - open file upload in asp.net. I voted to close your question because it has been answered many times and there are youtube videos. You have not done research. So, your question should be closed. [Also look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569565/uploading-files-in-asp-net-without-using-the-fileupload-server-control)

Comment: @Flydog57 Thank you for your response. Now I realized the difference.

Comment: @T.S. I searched for many hours but I was not hitting the right point in searching so it's fine to ask the question if I don't know, where I take a look about the previous questions in stack overflow and didn't find what I want or didn't know about what should I search.

Comment: You can ask the question. But you will not get an answer for such question. I searched google and in 5 seconds, I retrieved your answer multiple times